# sunrsasign.jar File Not Found Exception

Tags: java, exception, filenotfoundexception

In debug mode, am facing sunrsasign.jar File Not Found Exception

Exception thrown at :

String strFileGenerationDate = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());

Regards

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve]. Use the "edit" link to improve your *question* - do not add more information via comments. Thanks!

Comment: I am pretty sure that the above code alone will not allow us to repro your problem.

Comment: If ever there was a need for a question to include the full stack trace of the exception, it’s this time.  I can’t see how that code would generate a FileNotFoundException.